# Display Similar Items With Having Distinct Count Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display a list of gins that have a similar minimum number of botanicals on my show page. I feel I'm close, but the current output is not right. It's actually just printing the name of the gin a number of times.

> Gin Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "gins".* FROM "gins" INNER JOIN
>   "gins_botanicals" ON "gins_botanicals"."gin_id" = "gins"."id" INNER
>   JOIN "botanicals" ON "botanicals"."id" =
>   "gins_botanicals"."botanical_id" WHERE "botanicals"."id" IN (4, 10, 3)
>   AND ("gins"."id" != $1) GROUP BY gins.id HAVING (COUNT(distinct
>   botanicals.id) >= 3)  [["id", 2]]

I have three models; two resources with a joins table:

**gin.rb**

```
class Gin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :distillery, inverse_of: :gins
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :distillery, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}
  acts_as_punchable
  has_many :gins_botanical
  has_many :botanicals, through: :gins_botanical
```

**botanical.rb**

```
class Botanical < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :gins_botanical
  has_many :gins, through: :gins_botanical
```

**gins_botanical.rb**

```
class GinsBotanical < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gin
  belongs_to :botanical
```

**gins_controller**

```
  def show
    @gin = Gin.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gin.punch(request)
    @meta_title = meta_title @gin.name
    @similiar_gins = Gin.joins(:botanicals).where("botanicals.id" => @gin.botanical_ids).where.not('gins.id' => @gin.id).having("COUNT(distinct botanicals.id) >= 3").group("gins.id")
  end
```

so in `@similar_gins` i am trying to count how many matching botanicals does the current @gin have compared to all the other @gins and if >= 3 return the values.

And in my view:

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @similiar_gins.each do |gin| %>
  <%= @gin.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'm suspecting my `where` is not correct...

Comment: Do you want to list all `Gin` records having _at least_ 3 associated `Bonatical` records in common with `@gin`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the similar feature but I have implemented like below

```
@gin = Gin.find(params[:id])
if @gin.botanicals.count > 1
    @botanicals = @gin.botanical_ids
    @gin_ids = Botanical.select('distinct gin_id').where('gin_id IN (?)', @botanicals).limit(10)
    @ids = @gin_ids.map(&:gin_id)
    @similiar_gins = Gin.where('id IN (?)', @ids).where.not(id: @gin) #=> similar all without current gin
end
```

This code is converted from my code which is relation is `category` and `jobs`, if you need to see my code for showing the similar jobs then it is

```
def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.categories.count > 1
        @category = @job.category_ids
        @jobs = JobCategory.select('distinct job_id').where('category_id IN (?)', @category).limit(10)
        ids = @jobs.map(&:job_id)
        @releted_jobs = Job.where('id IN (?)', ids).where.not(id: @job)
    end
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @fool-dev. I get an error with `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: It happens when `through` id is null, like when any `Gin` without `Botanical` then it throws the error, I have updated my answer see this one @SimonCooper

Comment: Now can't find the `gin_id` column.  Is this looking up from the joins table as I don't have `gin_id` in the @botanicals table.  `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "gin_id" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT distinct gin_id FROM "botanicals" WHERE (gin_id IN (... ^ : SELECT distinct gin_id FROM "botanicals" WHERE (gin_id IN (4,10,3)) LIMIT $1`